# Integer equation with squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number. I want to show that if $x$, $y\in \mathbb{Z}$ satisfy the equation $y^2=x^3+px$, then $x$ is either a square or $p$ times a square.

My approach is to rewrite the equation as $y^2=x(x^2+p)$ and it can be shown that $x$ and $x^2+p$ are coprime. From there, I'd use Bezout's theorem that $\exists u$,$v\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $xu+(x^2+p)v=1$

I  tried letting $x^2+p=\frac{y^2}{x}$ and replacing in the Bezout identity but that didn't lead me anywhere. Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $d= gcd(x,y)$. Then exist $a,b$ relatively prime such that $x=da$ and $y=db$.
So 
$$d^2b^2 = d^3a^3+pda \Longrightarrow   db^2 = (d^2a^2+p)a  \Longrightarrow a|db^2$$

Since $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime we have $a|d$ so $d=ac$ for some integer $c$. Now we have:

$$c(b^2-a^4c) = p \;\;\Longrightarrow \;\;  c= 1\vee c= p$$

If $c=1$ we have $a=d$ and so $x=a^2$.

if $c=p$ we have $x= ad =a^2c = a^2p$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried to follow your approach by starting with a $gcd(x,y)=d$ and going through with the problem. I find the following equation $c(b^2-a^4c)=p$ not $c(b^2-ac)=p$. The final answer remains the same, however.

Comment: Ah, yes, you are correct!